# Multi Store with different actions

Tags: magento

I have a little problem:
I have a Magento site in which I have 2 (i can choose in frontend at any time) shops and I want to interact in two different forms. In one of them the shop will have a cart and prices and in the second one it will not have cart and prices so only customers can create budgets.
Is it possible determine what shop im in? I trying to use $_SERVER variables to manage shop1 and shop2 but this variable is restore to an initial value.
I’ll be waiting for your’re response, thank you in advance and sorry for poor language :smileytongue:.
Best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the storeCode if you just need to do a simple if else

```
 <?php
 $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
 ?>
```

Then in your template

```
 <?php if ( $storeCode === 'storenameA'): ?> 
  ...
 <?php else: ?> 
  ...               
 <?php endif; ?>
```